# How to stylize a form to make it REALLY FREAKING BIG

Tags: css, html, forms, styles

I want to make the default size of the input fields and button on my form 3X larger than normal as well as the text that appears inside the input fields be 3X larger than the default.

I've seen this done before but I'll be damned if I can even find any code to get me started.

Comment: http://getthiscrazyoffer.com/hiringnational/ the form appears toward the bottom of this page. I want it to be nice and BIG so people notice it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms

Comment: yeah I saw that page already, not much help

Answer (score 2):

To make the input fields and buttons bigger, you will need to use CSS Selectors to carry this out, I'll give you a quick example on a basic form:

HTML:

```
<form ID="Form" action="Contact.php" method="post">
     <!-- Standard input text boxes -->
     <input type="Text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
     <input type="Text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname">

     <!-- Submit button -->
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input[name=FirstName] {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[name=Surname] {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #DF0101; /* red */
    box-shadow: #6E7849 1px 1px 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle.net example of what I have just done, all the widths and heights etc can then be modified to suit your preference in the CSS stylesheet.

http://jsfiddle.net/tduagdnt/